# How to make bool variable only true if its being set to true?

Tags: c++

I have

```
namespace global {
    bool global::Aimbot; // this must be set to false until something else doesnt set this to true
}
```

in my function im doing

```
inline void set_view_angles()
{
    global::Aimbot = true;
    // so everytime this func is called it set global::Aimbot to true
}
```

I debugged `global::Aimbot bool`, and there is a problem.
If I call function `set_view_angles()`, `global::Aimbot` change from `false` to `true`, and its `true` every frame...
I want `global::Aimbot` to be only true when `set_view_angles()` is called.

Comment: Maybe unrelated, but I would consider thinking about whether a global mutable variable is the right approach. If there's any way to avoid that, remove it.

Comment: `bool Aimbot = false;` will do I assume

Comment: What does "frame" mean?

Comment: PS: global variables should always be zero initialized. Not sure if that holds if inside a namespace

Comment: OH my GOD, every tick

Comment: Well, it's a global variable. It starts as `false`. Then you call a function that sets it to `true`, and it stays `true` until something changes it. If you want it to be reset to `false` at the beginning of every "frame" or "tick", then assign `false` to it at the beginning of every "frame" or "tick".

Comment: @my frame or tick? Those aren't always the same. But let's call it every "event of significance". Try this. In English, describe when you want `global::Aimbot` to be set to `false`. AFTER YOU DESCRIBE IT IN ENGLISH, then implement that in code.

Comment: From what you described, you already got exactly what you wanted. Variable is `false` until `set_view_angles()` is called, then it is `true`. And it will remain `true` until you do `global::Aimbot = false;`.

Comment: how about adding `global::Aimbot = false;` at the end of `set_view_angles()`?

Comment: yes, Igor Tandetnik, I want to reset it to false if set_view_angles() is not called

Comment: I want global::Aimbot to be false if set_view_angles() is not being called

Comment: You have to clear up your language. You said "I want to reset it to false if set_view_angles() is not called", but `set_view_angles()` _**was indeed called**_, so, per your description, it must be `true`. You want it to be `false` when something else happens. What is it?

Comment: God damnit, the only normal person who understand my problem is Igor Tandetnik.
Okay here is another example.

I want boolean variable only true when I hold key.

Comment: Set `global::Aimbot` to `false` immediately before returning from `set_view_angles()`.   If any of the code (or functions called) by `set_view_angles()` may throw an exception, you will also need to deal with that - there are various options.

Comment: No, me and others also understood, but since Igor Tandetnik already told you what to do, and you still expect some answer, and still can't properly describe the problem in English, it means you yourself doesn't uderstand it.

Comment: If you want the boolean variable to only be true when you hold the key, then you want to set it true when you acquire the key, and you want to set it false when you release they key. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: yes problem solved lol thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question is open to multiple interpretation, first let me summarize the problem as I understood from the description and the comments: OP wants to set variable `global::Aimbot` to `true` when some key is pressed, and set it to `false` when said key is released.

Answering: When function `set_view_angles()` is called, it changes the state of the global variable `global::Aimbot` to `true`, and it will remain `true` until something changes it back to `false`, so you may want a new function to do the job. Something like:

```
inline void unset_view_angles()
{
    global::Aimbot = false;
}
```

C++ itself doesn't provide a way to know if a key is pressed or not, you must rely on some external library for that. In the code where you poll or wait for keyboard events, you must check for the state of the key, and call either `unset_view_angles()` or `set_view_angles()` accordingly. For instance, if the key is "Q" and you are polling keyboard events with SDL library, you would do:

```
SDL_Event event;
while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
    if(event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN && event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_q)
        set_view_angles();
    else if(event.type == SDL_KEYUP && event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_q)
        unset_view_angles();
}
```